# Problem with size of my SQL Server Log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my database on SQL 2008 Express Advanced

Recovery Model is full
AutoShrink is false

When I ran sp_spaceused, I got the following;

```
database_name           db_size         unallocated_space   
FreeLearningTuts        1398.13 MB       0.73 MB

reserved    data           index_size          unused
211216 KB   207024 KB      2944 KB      1248 KB
```

Out of this, the size of the tables is 150MB but db size shows 1398.13. It's probably the size of the log file. Can you tell what should I do to reduce the size of the Database.

Does anything look wrong with my DB from the figures above or are these the figures that a healthy db shows?

Answer (score 0):

Do you do regular log backups? If not, the log will keep growing until you hit the maximum db size for SQL Express.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant? If I truncate the log now, will it effect the DB. The DB is on a shared hosting so I have no control over backups.

Comment: The idea of recovery mode=full is that the transaction log grows until it is backed up. No transaction log backup means the transaction log will grow forever. If you can't set up log backups then recovery mode=simple might be an alternative.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Comment: That is assuming it is actually in full mode and not pseudo-full mode, if the log is not being backed up, there is no guarentee that the first full db backup occured either.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, but either way: the problem at hand is a mismatch between the chosen recovery mode and the backup strategy...